# "npm install -g firebase-tools" not working

Tags: firebase, npm, installation

Trying to install firebase for flutter using "npm". Giving 10 vulnerabilities.

expecting to install firebase successfully with 0 vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `firebase-tools` itself use various packages like `request`, the version used it outdated or deprecated hence the vulnerability warning, you can use `firebase-tools` without any problem as it's normal for the packages to be deprecated.